# How to render component at a different dom element

Tags: reactjs

I have the following structure:

```
<Header />
<Subheader>
   <Breadcrumbs />
   <Submenu />
</Subheader>
<Main />
<Footer />
```

In the main component, I have constructed a dynamic menu, like so

```
<ul>
   <li>#1</li>
   <li>#2</li>
   <li>#3</li>
</ul>
```

to serve as the submenu, how do I render it to the `<Submenu />` DOM instead of the `<Main />` DOM where the menu is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wrapping container for all of this (maybe it's called `<App />`) give `<Main />` a function prop called something like sendSubmenu. When you have the Submenu info, call that function and then `<App />` can use setState to save it.  App can then pass the state value down to `<Subheader />` and `<Submenu />`.

You should probably leave the rendering of the data to the Submenu component though and just send it an array of information to render in the list.

Vague sketch:

```
<App>
  <Header />
  <Subheader subMenu={this.state.subMenu}> // State from App
     <Breadcrumbs />
     <Submenu data={this.props.submenu} /> // Props from Subheader
 </Subheader>
  <Main sendSubmenu={function (data) { this.setState({subMenu: data}) } />
  <Footer />
</App>
```

This all could be a bit easier if you were using a state manager like Redux.

---

Edit: To answer you questions more fully though, you could send a component in the same way I outlined above, and when it's received in the Submenu do something like:

```
const List = this.props.data;
return <List />;
```

This should style should be used with caution though. It's confusing where the full component is coming from.